# Excel VBA event to delete picture on a particular cell generate error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program to remove a picture from range A of the line where there is a selection change.
When there is a picture it gets deleted, but when there is no picture, the program generate an error message "Application-defined or object defined error. Not sure what the problem is. Thanks for your help.
below is the program

```
Function boolPicDelete(chkRange As Range)
    Dim sh As Shape

    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If sh.TopLeftCell.Row = chkRange.Row Then
            sh.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sh
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    boolPicDelete (Cells(Target.Row, 1))
End Sub
```

Comment: Hm, I just tested it with an image with the top left corner in A52, and it worked for me without any errors.  What line is throwing the error?  Also, technically, you don't have a [`SelectionChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx), but a `Change` event. The difference being a cell value must actually change (or at least enter a cell and exit it) before it'll run.  If you simply want it to run each time you *select* a different cell, do `Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(...`

Comment: Thank you for testing, it works when there is a picture, but test it when there is no picture to delete and see if you get a "Application-defined or object defined error'. That's what i am getting

Comment: oh, so you may not have a picture? If there's no picture then I assume you don't want to delete anything.  Try adding this before the `For` loop: `If Active sheet.shapes.count = 0 then exit sub`